# R: Time Efficient Way of Renaming Columns/Rows of a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a more efficient way of doing this:
The matrix `expr` is 15745 x 41

```
for (i in 1:ncol(expr)){
   colnames(expr)[i] <- paste0("V",i);
}
for (i in 1:nrow(expr)){
   rownames(expr)[i] <- paste0(i);
}
```

Comment: I download the data from GEO (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/) so I am not sure if I can this at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dimnames` to do this

```
dimnames(expr) <- list(seq_len(nrow(expr)), paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(expr))))
```

---

Or this can be also done with explicitly assigning `colnames` and `rownames` as we have commented earlier

```
colnames(expr) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(expr)))
rownames(expr) <- seq_len(nrow(expr))
```

---

Or another option is to convert it to `data.frame` which will automatically do the naming (if working with `data.frame` is okay)

```
as.data.frame(expr)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
expr <- matrix(rnorm(10*5), 10, 5)
```

Comment: This is nice. A few questions though: 
what is `seq_len` doing. Also yes I convert the matrix into data frame right after the above loops but I need to look up `seed` and `rnorm` to use it.

Comment: I feel I have written very inefficient code. I think I should have converted it into data frame before renaming it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It just should 2 hours ago for both the answers and I was not sure.

Comment: While we are at this. Can you answer this question too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616470/r-objnametolist-on-some-particular-list-of-objects-in-parent-frame

Comment: Also I had problem with converting graphNEL objects into Adjacency Matrix. If you can answer this query (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588079/r-how-to-convert-graphnel-object-into-adjacency-matrix). If you can help out I would be grateful. There is not much help available for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
colnames(expr) <- paste0("V",1:ncol(expr))
rownames(expr) <- 1:nrow(expr)
```

Comment: smooth! Thanks a bunch.